# Calendar list, for changing set of months

Tags: php, calendar, while-loop, date, strtotime

So I spent all day writing this page to pull the meetings stored in a table for a particular group,

discard any meetings older than 4 months, and further in the future than 10 months, so it shows a year worth of meetings but starting with 3 months ago so you can see what has happened recently if you want in addition to what is going to happen.

Everything works - except the comparison of days +/- dates seams very literal
and I ran a test today on the 27th,  and the meetings I have in the DB on the 28th and 30th show up in Jan.

*Can I Round the date to the first of the current month?*

**and is there a easier way to write this code?**

PHP code:

```
// post variables
$ScoutID=$_POST['ScoutID'];
$Rank=$_POST['Rank'];
$DenID=$_POST['DenID'];
// Define Dates
$Date = date("Y-m-d");
$Month1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3 months"));
$Month2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-2 months"));
$Month3 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 months"));
$Month4 = $Date;
$Month5 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 months"));
$Month6 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 months"));
$Month7 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 months"));
$Month8 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+4 months"));
$Month9 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+5 months"));
$Month10 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+6 months"));
$Month11 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+7 months"));
$Month12 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+8 months"));
$Month12 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+9 months"));
//counter variables to print the month header
$M1=0;
$M2=0;
$M3=0;
$M4=0;
$M5=0;
$M6=0;
$M7=0;
$M8=0;
$M9=0;
$M10=0;
$M12=0;
$M12=0;

//Find Den Number from Den ID
$resultb = mysql_query('SELECT Den FROM Dens WHERE DenID = "'.$DenID.'"');
    if (!resultb)
    {
    die('Could not query:' .mysql_error());
    }
$DenNum = mysql_result($resultb,0);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM DenMeetings WHERE DenID = "'.$DenID.'" ORDER BY Date'; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {

    if($row['Date'] > $Month1 && $row['Date'] < $Month2)
        {
        if($M1 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month2));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M1++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month2 && $row['Date'] < $Month3)
        {
        if($M2 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month3));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 2 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M2++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 2 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month3 && $row['Date'] < $Month4)
        {
        if($M3 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month4));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 3 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M3++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 3 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month4 && $row['Date'] < $Month5)
        {
        if($M4 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month5));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M4++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month5 && $row['Date'] < $Month6)
        {
        if($M5 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month6));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M5++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month6 && $row['Date'] < $Month7)
        {
        if($M6 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month7));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M6++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month7 && $row['Date'] < $Month8)
        {
        if($M7 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month8));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M7++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month8 && $row['Date'] < $Month9)
        {
        if($M8 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month9));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M8++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month9 && $row['Date'] < $Month10)
        {
        if($M9 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month10));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M9++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month10 && $row['Date'] < $Month11)
        {
        if($M10 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month11));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M10++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month11 && $row['Date'] < $Month12)
        {
        if($M11 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month12));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M11++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    else if($row['Date'] > $Month12 && $row['Date'] < $Month13)
        {
        if($M12 < 1)
            {
            echo '<h2>';
            echo strftime('%B',strtotime($Month11));
            echo '</h2>';

            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            $M12++;
            }
        else 
            {
            echo $row['Date'];
            echo ' - 1 - ';
            echo $row['Notes'];
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }   
    else
        {

        }
    }
```

Output - Notice the dates in Jan:

> November
>
> 2011-11-26 - 2 - 1 month
>
> December
>
> 2011-12-15 - 3 -
>
> 2011-12-20 - 3 - test32
>
> 2011-12-24 - 3 - test
>
> 2011-12-26 - 3 - today
>
> January
>
> **2011-12-28 - 1 - test
>
> 2011-12-30 - 1 - test**
>
> 2012-01-05 - 1 - test23
>
> 2012-01-13 - 1 - 12
>
> 2012-01-13 - 1 - 12
>
> 2012-01-13 - 1 - 12
>
> 2012-01-20 - 1 - 32w45
>
> April
>
> 2012-04-26 - 1 - +4 months
>
> 2012-04-26 - 1 - +4 months

Comment: There has *got* to be a better way to do this - and I bet it starts with a `for` loop.

Comment: It has to do with [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) as well

Comment: I got the rounding the month part.....

Comment: $Month12 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 second",strtotime("+10 month",strtotime(date("m")."/01/".date("Y")." 00:00:00"))));

Answer (score 0):

It's Christmas, so here ya go.  It does everything you requested (I think) plus adds a layer of flexibility.

A few bits could be optimized but it works pretty well.

```
$data = array();

// Generate some random dates to simulate database output, then sort.
for($x=0;$x<100;$x++) {
  $day = sprintf("%02s", rand(1,29));
  $month = sprintf("%02s", rand(1,12));
  $year = rand(2011, 2013);
  $data[] = array("Date"=>$year."-".$month."-".$day, "Notes"=>"Entry ".$x);
}

sort($data);

// Calculate start/end timestamps (YYYYMM) according to 
// start/end index prefs and current year
$startIndex = -3;
$endIndex = 9;
$startTimestamp = date("Ym", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n') + $startIndex, 1, 2012));
$endTimestamp = date("Ym", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n') + $endIndex, 1, 2012));

// Loop through data
$previous = "";
for($y=0;$y<count($data);$y++) {
  // Create timestamp for comparison (YYYYMM)
  // by removing delimiter in "date" value.
  $entry = $data[$y];
  $date = explode("-", $entry["Date"]);
  $timestamp = $date[0].$date[1];

  // If the timestamp is outside of the start/end timestamps,
  // tell loop to move on to next value
  if($timestamp < $startTimestamp || $timestamp > $endTimestamp) {
    continue;
  }

  // If the timestamp has changed month,
  // output the title of the new month
  if($timestamp != $previous) {
    echo "<br /><b>";
    echo date("F Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[1], 1, $date[0]));
    echo "</b><br />";
  }

  // Finally, output individual values
  echo $entry["Date"].": ".$entry["Notes"]."<br />";

  // Save current timestamp for comparison on the next round
  $previous = $timestamp;
}
```

*EDIT The first part is just simulating data from your database, you can cut that out as you need of course.  The core of it is the for loop in the middle.*

Output:

[image]

Comment: I love how simple this is compaired to mine, and I obviously have a lot to learn in PHP.  But you generated an array where each part of that array was Year-Month-Date-Notes and you exploded those to print them on the screen,  my query does not put the info in that format,  how do i get $query = 'SELECT * FROM DenMeetings WHERE DenID = "'.$DenID.'" ORDER BY Date'; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   To fit into your script?